# Getting conflicting results for the rate of change of the volume of a cube given rate of change of the length of an edge

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the initial edge length of a cube is $l_0$ and it is expanding at the rate $\alpha.$ Thus we can write its edge length as
$$ l(t) = l_0 + \alpha t. \tag1$$
So, its volume is
$$ V(t) = (l(t))^3 =  (l_0 + \alpha t)^3. \tag2$$
So, its rate of change of volume is
$$  \dot{V}=\frac{dV}{dt} = 3\alpha(l_0+\alpha t)^2. \tag3$$

Now, let's say that $l_0 = 1$ and $\alpha = 2$. Then $V(0) = 1,$ while $V(1) = 27,$ so the change in volume is $V(1)-V(0) =26,$ so the rate of change of volume from $t=0$ to $t=1$ is $$\dot{V}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} = 26.$$ But equation $(3)$ gives $$\dot{V} = 3(2)(1+2(1))^2 =54$$ instead!  I don't understand why I'm getting two different results?

Comment: $\frac{dV}{dt}$ when $t=1$ is how rapidly the volume is changing at that time, in units of volume/time unit. It is not the total change in $V$ for a unit change in $t$.

Comment: The derivative represents the *instantaneous* rate of change, while you're computing the change over a large period.

Comment: As @Paul mentioned, the instantaneous rate of change of the volume at t=1 is 54($\frac{\text{length units}^3}{\text{time units}}$), while the total change of volume from t=0 to t=1 is 80(units of volume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the rate of change of volume from $t=0$ to $t=1$ is $$\dot{V}=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} = 26.$$

Equation $(3)$ tells us that the rate of change of volume **continually varies** between $t=0$ and $t=1;$ what you've computed above is the ***average*** rate of change of volume from $t=0$ to $t=1.$

> But equation $(3)$ gives $$\dot{V} = 3(2)(1+2(1))^2 =54$$ instead!

What you've computed above is **not** the rate of change of volume from $t=0$ to $t=1,$ but the ***instantaneous*** rate of change of volume at $t=1.$

Answer (score 1):

actualy they don't have to give the same result
because $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} = \frac{d V}{d t}  $ only when $\Delta t $ approaches 0 , so the two results will be approximately the same when using values near 1 (0.99 for example)

the first method you used gives the rate of change between 0 and 1 (long period)
while the other one gives the rate of change at the point (1,27)

[here
the blue line is what the derivative gives
and the green one is what the $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} $ method gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIvMn.png)